# How do I transform my data so that my regressions produce meaningful coefficients?

Tags: r, database, regression

Hi I am a novice in doing regressions and programming in R in general. In my free time, I have started with a project of analyzing the impact of COVID pandemic on US counties.

I have a data frame that contains the following columns: id of the county, change in spending in the county vs spending in the first week of January (in %), change in spending for each week vs spending last week (in %), median household income in the county, case rate for the county in the week and past 7 days average of new cases.

What I am trying to determine is the link between the spending and the income and case rates. However, the problem is that the spending is given as porcentual change while the case rates are absolute values.

Therefore when I run a regression of the change in spending on case rate, what I essentially get is the coefficient that says by how many percent does spending change in the week for one more case. I am guessing that is not ideal for data analysis.

How would you change the case rate data so that it better corresponds to the spending data and the coefficients of my regressions can be more easily interpreted?

Answer (score 0):

If you are assuming that the case rate is a function of spending, you are going to need to get the baseline spending, and then use the changes to fill in the values for the spending for each period.  (Unless there's some methodology I'm not familiar with).  You can probably get that starting value with a few phone calls.

Consider the following dataset:

```
spending  spending_change rate previous_rate
1700      0.0625           900   700
1800      0.058823529     1065   900
1900      0.055555556     1200  1065
2000      0.052631579     1305  1200
2100      0.05            1380  1305
2220      0.057142857     1419  1380
2330      0.04954955      1425  1419
2450      0.051502146     1395  1425
2570      0.048979592     1329  1395
2700      0.050583658     1224  1329
2850      0.055555556     1074  1224
```

Other than the first row, rate = previous_rate+(2350-spending)*0.3
Where rate = the number of infections. (I made up this data.)

Using linear regression:
`lm(rate ~ previous_rate, data=testdata)`
gives an r-squared of 0.77, and previous_rate has a significance of 0.00025
`lm(rate ~ spending + previous_rate, data=testdata)`
gives an r-squared of 1 (nearly perfect model), and both predictors are significant at e-16.
`lm(rate ~ spending_change + previous_rate, data=testdata)`
gives an r-squared of 0.74, previous_rate has a significance of 0.02, and spending change has a significance of 0.89.  The model is slightly worse than the first model.

As you can see, the change in spending was worthless.
You want a high r-squared, and low coefficients mean the predictors are significant.

Using a random forest with defaults:
`randomForest(formula = rate ~ spending + previous_rate, data = testdata)`
The variance explained = 47.14%
Using `previous_rate` the variance explained is 34.8%.
Using `spending_change + previous_rate` the variance explained is 29.0%
Using `spending` the variance explained is 56.8%
Using `spending_change` the variance explained is 0.01%

I included the random forest results to show the methodology won't pick up the significance of spending_change here.

**The above is intended to show that you need the actual spending, and is not intended to be a recommendation of what modeling type to use.**